# Find Index of first Matching Element $gte with $indexOfArray

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, array-indexing

MongoDB has `$indexOfArray` to let you find the element's array index, for example:

```
$indexOfArray: ["$article.date", ISODate("2019-03-29")]
```

Is it possible to use comparison operators with `$indexOfArray` together, like:

```
$indexOfArray: ["$article.date", {$gte: ISODate("2019-03-29")}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not it's not possible with [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) as that will only look for an *equality match* to an expression as the second argument.

Instead you can make a construct like this:

```
db.data.insertOne({
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca01e301a97dd8b468b3f55"),
    "array" : [
            ISODate("2018-03-01T00:00:00Z"),
            ISODate("2018-03-02T00:00:00Z"),
            ISODate("2018-03-03T00:00:00Z")
    ]
})

db.data.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "matchedIndex": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "matched": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              { "$filter": {
                "input": {
                  "$zip": {
                    "inputs": [ "$array", { "$range": [ 0, { "$size": "$array" } ] }]
                  }
                },
                "cond": { "$gte": [ { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$this", 0] }, new Date("2018-03-02") ] }
              }},
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [{ "$ifNull": [ "$$matched", [0,-1] ] },1]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which would return for the [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) of `Date("2018-03-02")`:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ca01e301a97dd8b468b3f55"),
        "array" : [
                ISODate("2018-03-01T00:00:00Z"),
                ISODate("2018-03-02T00:00:00Z"),
                ISODate("2018-03-03T00:00:00Z")
        ],
        "matchedIndex" : 1
}
```

Or `-1` where the condition was not met in order to be consistent with [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/).

The basic premise is using [`$zip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) in order to "pair" with the array index positions which get generated from [`$range`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the array. This can be fed to a [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) condition which will return *ALL matching elements* to the supplied condition. Here it is the *first* element of the "pair" ( being the original array content ) via [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) matching the specified condition using [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/)

```
{ "$gte": [ { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$this", 0] }, new Date("2018-03-02") ] }
```

The [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) will return either ALL elements after ( in the case of [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) ) or an empty array where nothing was found. Consistent with [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) you only want the **first match**, which is done with another wrapping [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) on the output for the `0` position.

Since the result could be an omitted value ( which is what happens by `$arrayElemAt: [[], 0]` ) then you use [`$ifNull][8]` to test the result ans pass a two element array back with a `-1` as the second element in the case where the output was not defined. In either case that "paired" array has the second element ( index `1` ) extracted again via [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) in order to get the *first matched index* of the condition.

Of course since you want to refer to that whole expression, it just reads a little cleaner in the end within a [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/), but that is optional as you can "inline" with the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) if wanted.

So it is *possible*, it's just a little more involved than placing a range expression inside of [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/).

Note that any *expression* which actually returns a *single value for equality match* is just fine. But since operators like [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) return a `boolean`, then that would not be *equal* to any value in the array, and thus the sort of processing with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and then extraction is what you require.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The articles were $push into the array, I was thinking to use first unread article array index compare with array size to figure out unread count, trying to avoid scan the whole array. It seems it would be more efficient just use $filter && $size. Thanks again anyway.